# Is find_one_and_update() in pymongo atomic?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, atomic

I couldn't find any documentation stating that `find_one_and_update()` in `pymongo` is atomic (i.e., no change on the document can appear between search and update). Can I rely on it being atomic? Or is there another way to perform the same operations in a guaranteed atomic way?

Comment: See [Update Documents- Atomicity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#atomicity).

Comment: @prasad_ I know that this operation is atomic if I use it with MongoDB directly. But as `pymongo` is a python package, can I rely that using this function from python will be translated in an atomic request in MongoDB?

Comment: The update is executed on the database server - that is where it is atomic. PyMongo driver doesn't update the document - it translates the language specific data/command and passes it to the server (where it is an atomic operation). PyMongo then receives the update confirmation. The driver, in addition does things like providing the connection to the server, converting data from/to the client types to Bson types on the server.

Comment: @prasad_ So I can assume that using this function in PyMongo will directly translate to the corresponding `findOneAndUpdate` MongoDB method as described in the MongoDB manual? My concern was that someone else might change the document between the filter/query step and the update step, and that I'm not sure whether the PyMongo function `find_one_and_update()` directly translates to `findOneAndUpdate`. (Feel free to write it as an answer so that I can accept it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyMongo's `find_one_and_update` is atomic as it translates to server's `findOneAndUpdate` which is atomic (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity).

However, be aware of the "glitch" when upserting new documents. When not using a unique index on the query field(s), multiple instances of a `findOneAndUpdate` operation with similar query field(s) could result in duplicate documents being inserted in certain circumstances. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#upsert-with-unique-index)